# html sanitizer remove custom tag and keep inner content

Tags: html, tags

How can i remove all unknown existings custom tags keeping html content in this following example :

```
<div>
  <h1>my header</h1>
  <custom:p>
     <h2>my Title</h2>
  </custom:p>
  <anothercustom:p>
     <h3>my SubTitle</h3>
  </anothercustom:p>
</div>
```

I would like to return

```
<div>
  <h1>my header</h1>
  <h2>my Title</h2>
  <h3>my SubTitle</h3>
</div>
```

Is there any solution with HTML sanitizer ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I've been looking for the same thing. I found that `HtmlSanitizer` has a `KeepChildNodes` option in version 3.4.156, which I'm using, that does exactly this.

```
var sanitizer = new HtmlSanitizer();
sanitizer.KeepChildNodes = true;
sanitizer.Sanitize(html);
```

Comment: Note that this keeps the Content of ALL Tags, also of script tags.

Comment: @dummdidumm - Yes, but this still seems safe as it'll encode the tags to HTML entities so they won't be executable. You can see example of the output here - https://xss.ganss.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `HtmlSanitizer.RemovingTag` event to keep the contents of the tag:

```
        var sanitizer = new HtmlSanitizer();

        sanitizer.RemovingTag += (sender, args) =>
        {
            args.Tag.OuterHtml = sanitizer.Sanitize(args.Tag.InnerHtml);
            args.Cancel = true;
        };

        var sanitized = sanitizer.Sanitize("<unknown>this will not be removed</unknown>");
```

Comment: Note that this also keeps the content of script Tags. To prevent this: `sanitizer.RemovingTag += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (!args.Tag.Matches("script")) 
                {
                    args.Tag.OuterHtml = sanitizer.Sanitize(args.Tag.InnerHtml);
                    args.Cancel = true;
                }
            };`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the htmlSanitizer for .net on git hub https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer

You can modify the opensource project to preserve the content of the tags
Change the RemoveTag method of the HtmlSanitize class as follows:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Remove a tag from the document.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="tag">to be removed</param>
        private void RemoveTag(IDomObject tag)
        {
            var e = new RemovingTagEventArgs { Tag = tag };
            OnRemovingTag(e);
            if (!e.Cancel)
            {
                // tag.Remove();<<remove this;

                //replace it with this vvvvvvvvvvvvvv
                tag.OuterHTML = this.Sanitize(tag.InnerHTML);
            }
        }
```